# knife ec2 to vpc node

Tags: amazon-ec2, automation, chef-infra, knife

I am trying to launch node in EC2 VPC using chef knife ec2 server create to launch ec2 instance into VPC, But I looking a flag to specify vpc info.

Anyone know how to spin up ec2 instance into vpc using knife ec2 server create ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `--subnet SUBNET_ID` flag for `knife ec2` command. You can specify which subnet of VPC you want the instance be created using this flag.

Refer: https://docs.chef.io/plugin_knife_ec2.html

You cannot provide VPC identity. However, you can provide subnet identity which eventually will create the instance in your VPC of choice.